# Finding all instances of substring within DataTable of strings C#

Tags: c#, list, datatable, substring

As the title reads, I currently have a Datatable with a single column, multiple rows containing strings. I am looking to extract all instances of the 'Order Number' from each of these rows, there may be multiple order numbers per row.

Below is an example of a single row within the datatable with multiple order numbers:

> "\r\nYour Dispatch Advice Confirmation was Successful \r\nThe details of the Dispatch Advice Confirmation are shown below. \r\n\r\nSite Name:  Germany \r\nCountry:  Germany \r\nInvestigator Name:  Inv Name \r\nOrder Number:  **111** \r\nActual Date of Dispatch:  26/Apr/2021 \r\nActual Time of Dispatch:  14:01 \r\nLatest Acceptable Date of Receipt:  29/Apr/2021 \r\nLatest Acceptable Time of Receipt:  14:01 \r\nCourier:   \r\nAirway Bill Number:   \r\nReference:   \r\nNon-Uniquely Labelled Medication:- \r\nTotal Quantity of Kits:  20 \r\n\r\nSite Name:  Germany \r\nCountry:  Germany \r\nInvestigator Name:  Inv Name \r\nOrder Number:  **112** \r\nActual Date of Dispatch:  26/Apr/2021 \r\nActual Time of Dispatch:  07:00 \r\nLatest Acceptable Date of Receipt:  29/Apr/2021 \r\nLatest Acceptable Time of Receipt:  14:01 \r\nCourier:   \r\nAirway Bill Number:   \r\nReference:   \r\nNon-Uniquely Labelled Medication:- \r\nTotal Quantity of Kits:  10

Essentially I need to loop through each row in the datatable and extract every order number (only the number), then dump them in a int list or something to that effect.
In all honesty I have no idea how to proceed with this as it's my first time using Datatables:

```
public void generateResponseList(Schedule theSchedule)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT Body FROM Responses WHERE responseDefID = 4 AND ResponseType = 1";

        sql = Utils.GetSQL(theSchedule.ParentStudy, sql);
        System.Data.DataTable table = theSchedule.ParentStudy.TheDatabase.GetDataTable(sql);

        string test2;
        foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            test2 = row["Body"].ToString();
            //var value = row["Body"].ToString().Substring(0, row["Body"].ToString().LastIndexOf('=') + 1);
        }
    }
```

Currently test2 will equate to each row, the sperg of text listed above.

Any help is much appreciated!

**Edit:** It's come to my attention that the output above may have borked formatting due to my conversion to string. Viewing the rows in Dataset visualizer formats correctly:

> Your Dispatch Advice Confirmation was Successful  The details of the
> Dispatch Advice Confirmation are shown below.
>
> Depot:  Grenzach (EU) Depot  Site Number:  49001  Site Name:  Germany
> Country:  Germany  Investigator Name:  Inv Name  Order Number:  111
> Actual Date of Dispatch:  26/Apr/2021  Actual Time of Dispatch:  14:01
> Latest Acceptable Date of Receipt:  29/Apr/2021  Latest Acceptable
> Time of Receipt:  14:01  Courier:    Airway Bill Number:    Reference:
> Non-Uniquely Labelled Medication:-  Total Quantity of Kits:  20
>
> Depot:  San Francisco (USA) Depot  Site Number:  49001  Site Name:
> Germany  Country:  Germany  Investigator Name:  Inv Name  Order
> Number:  112  Actual Date of Dispatch:  26/Apr/2021  Actual Time of
> Dispatch:  07:00  Latest Acceptable Date of Receipt:  29/Apr/2021
> Latest Acceptable Time of Receipt:  14:01  Courier:    Airway Bill
> Number:    Reference:    Non-Uniquely Labelled Medication:-  Total
> Quantity of Kits:  10

I can't imagine this will change the substring call too much but worth bearing in mind!

**Solved**

For anyone that stumbles across this in the future, had to edit the regex slightly to account for the white space between "order number:" and the number. Could also be achieved by removing all white spaces I imagine.
Also changed to output to string list:

```
public void generateResponseList(Schedule theSchedule)
    {
        //generates respList of orders that have recieved responses
        string sql = "SELECT Body FROM Responses WHERE responseDefID = 4 AND ResponseType = 1";

        sql = Utils.GetSQL(theSchedule.ParentStudy, sql);
        System.Data.DataTable table = theSchedule.ParentStudy.TheDatabase.GetDataTable(sql);

        var respList = new List<string>();

        string pattern = @"Order Number: (?'OrderNum'\s\d+)";
        foreach (DataRow row in table.AsEnumerable())
        {
            string data = row.Field<string>(0);
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(data, pattern);
            respList.AddRange(matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["OrderNum"].Value).ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication189
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Body",typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { " Name Order Number: 112 \n  Name Order Number: 113 \n  Name Order Number: 114" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { " Name Order Number: 212 \n  Name Order Number: 213 \n  Name Order Number: 214" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { " Name Order Number: 312 \n  Name Order Number: 313 \n  Name Order Number: 314" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { " Name Order Number: 412 \n  Name Order Number: 413 \n  Name Order Number: 414" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { " Name Order Number: 512 \n  Name Order Number: 513 \n  Name Order Number: 514" });


            string pattern = @"Order Number: (?'OrderNum'\d+)";
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                string data = row.Field<string>(0);
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(data, pattern);
                string[] ordNums = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["OrderNum"].Value).ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", ordNums));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
 
        }
    }
  
}
```